# Alternative to the deprecated AudioManager.isWiredHeadsetOn?

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

The method [AudioManager.isWiredHeadsetOn()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#isWiredHeadsetOn%28%29) is deprecated from api level 14, how do we now detect if a wired headset is connected?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The documentation's deprecation message states:

> Use only to check is a headset is connected or not.

So I guess it is okay to keep using it to check whether or not a wired headset is connected, but not to check whether or not audio is being routed to it or played over it.

Comment: I guess the answer is as simple as that. I find it confusing to deprecate a method, if its not really deprecated, it just changed purpose a bit. Anyway, thanks. :)

Answer (score 28):

This is my solution:

```
private boolean isHeadsetOn(Context context) {
    AudioManager am = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    if (am == null)
        return false;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        return am.isWiredHeadsetOn() || am.isBluetoothScoOn() || am.isBluetoothA2dpOn();
    } else {
        AudioDeviceInfo[] devices = am.getDevices(AudioManager.GET_DEVICES_OUTPUTS);

        for (AudioDeviceInfo device : devices) {
            if (device.getType() == AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_WIRED_HEADSET
                    || device.getType() == AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_WIRED_HEADPHONES
                    || device.getType() == AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_BLUETOOTH_A2DP
                    || device.getType() == AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_BLUETOOTH_SCO) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The deprecation of `isWiredHeadsetOn` and `isBluetoothA2dpOn` is from API 14. What should have been done between 14 and before M (23) ? I think even the docs are weird here, so I wrote this: issuetracker.google.com/issues/111788828  . Anyway, is it expected to work fine with this workaround for accepting calls : https://stackoverflow.com/a/29651130/878126 (replacement for `isWiredHeadsetOn`) ?

Comment: Maybe you have to expand your solution,
The document said that 
TYPE_WIRED_HEADSET:
A device type describing a headset, which is the combination of a headphones and microphone.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioDeviceInfo.html#TYPE_WIRED_HEADSET

Answer (score 11):

Try this solution. It's working in my case. May be this helps you!

```
IntentFilter iFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
Intent iStatus = context.registerReceiver(null, iFilter);
boolean isConnected = iStatus.getIntExtra("state", 0) == 1;
```

Comment: But this won't tell you about the headset state when you plug in the headset BEFORE launching your app.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me correctly:

```
if(context.registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG)).getIntExtra("state", 0)==1){
//if(audioManager.isWiredHeadsetOn()){
    System.out.println("Headset is wiredOn");
}
else{
    System.out.println("Headset is not wiredOn");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
IntentFilter iFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
Intent iStatus = context.registerReceiver(null, iFilter);
boolean isConnected = iStatus.getIntExtra("state", 0) == 1;
```

I do know this code can be used on which andorid platform version.
It does not work for me on Android 8.
Result iStatus is null.

Answer (score -2):

we have to be using broadcast Receivers for finding the status of bluetooth connection.

Here is a good [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13610258/how-to-detect-when-a-user-plugs-headset-on-android-device-opposite-of-action-a?answertab=oldest#tab-top)