# How to force sound file to play only with headphones in android

Tags: android, audio, headphones

I am working on an app and I need to play a sound file only with headphones, no speakers, no earpiece weather headphone is plugged or not, on switch buttons' on or off state. I have written below code for that.

```
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                    if(mPrefs.getBoolean("flow_recording", false)){
                        audioManager.setWiredHeadsetOn(true);
                        audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
                    }
                    else{
                        audioManager.setWiredHeadsetOn(false);
                        audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
                    }
                    mPlayer.start();
```

but it still plays the audio with speakers when I unplug the headphone.

Please guide me to achieve this.

Comment: you plug headphones after playing the audio ?

Comment: no, I play it with and without headphone. In both conditions it is playing but I only want it play with headphone.

Comment: You should check whether headphone is plugged in or not. Play the sound if headphone is plugged in. See here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16395054/check-whether-headphones-are-plugged-in

Comment: It means you want to not play it if no headphones are connected ?

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain  Yes, I want it to play only with headphone when mPrefs.getBoolean("flow_recording", false) condition is true.

Comment: from where `mPrefs.getBoolean("flow_recording", false)` this pref is coming ? Are you setting it your self ? if yes on what basis ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I have resolved this issue with the help of this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16395054/check-whether-headphones-are-plugged-in)

Below is my working code:-

```
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            if(mPrefs.getBoolean("flow_recording", false)){
                /*audioManager.setWiredHeadsetOn(true);
                audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);*/
                if(audioManager.isWiredHeadsetOn() && mPlayer != null){
                    Log.e("HeadPhone", "Playing via headphone");
                    mPlayer.start();
                }
            }
            else{
                if(audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn() && mPlayer != null){
                    Log.e("Speaker", "Playing via speaker");
                    mPlayer.start();
                }
                /*audioManager.setWiredHeadsetOn(false);
                audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);*/
            }
```