# How can I detect if there is physical headphone jack in Android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I thought there is always a headphone jack in Android phone.

However, few days ago, I found that there is no headphone jack to plugin my headphone on OPPO R8106.

Is there any way to detect if there is headphone jack existing on Android?

My workaround solution is to register a `BroadcastReceiver` , if BroadcastReceiver receive a message in 5 second, I would thing there is a headphonce jack in this phone.

Any convenient way existing?

Comment: Are you talking about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16395054/check-whether-headphones-are-plugged-in

Comment: NO, the article is just detect whether if headphone plugged in. I want to detect whether if physical headphone jack exist.