# Android: Detect current audio channel

Tags: android, audio, bluetooth, android-audiomanager, audio-route

I'm looking to detect how the audio is currently being outputted in my android phone.

I've been testing with:

```
android.bluetooth.headset.profile.action.AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED
```

Which offers information when the current audio device is a bluetooth head phone and when it is not, which is part of the solution.

However, I cannot seem to capture when the audio is being routed to the speakers versus the receiver versus wired headphones.

Ideally, there would be one broadcast which I am listening to, that fires whenever the audio route changes, such as when toggling between them during a call.

Answer (score 0):

There is `AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY` intent which fires when the sound is being switched from headphones to speakers (see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#noisyintent).

And there is also a way for detecting the opposite switch, see [How to detect when a user plugs headset on android device? (Opposite of ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13610258/how-to-detect-when-a-user-plugs-headset-on-android-device-opposite-of-action-a)