# How To Detect A Headset Plugged In on Android 8.0 with targetSDKVersion >= 26

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver, android-8.0-oreo

Before Android 8.0, Oreo, you could [detect a headset plugged in with a background service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13610712/1858524) with a registered broadcast. With Android O's background execution limits, you can no longer do this without a notification.

While ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG is an excepted broadcast, it still doesn't send to Manifest registered receivers.

So you cannot use a background service. And you cannot be woken up via a manifest receiver. What's the solution? Never update your targetSDKVersion?

Comment: As I think this is an overlooked repercussion of Android 8.0, I've filed an issue with the framework team. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65672608

Answer (score 0):

Seems, by official documentation, you can use `ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG` with no Android O limitation, because it is in the [list of the exempted broadcasts](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions.html):

> Note: A number of implicit broadcasts are currently exempted from this
>   limitation. Apps can continue to register receivers for these
>   broadcasts in their manifests, no matter what API level the apps are
>   targeting. For a list of the exempted broadcasts, see [Implicit
>   Broadcast Exceptions](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions.html).

**UPDATE:**

But IRL, as [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) wrote, there are only

[`intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY);`](http://aosp.opersys.com/xref/android-8.0.0_r4/xref/frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/audio/AudioService.java#5318)

flag for `ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG` and not `Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_INCLUDE_BACKGROUND` flag as, for example, for [`ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED`](http://aosp.opersys.com/xref/android-8.0.0_r4/xref/frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java#20339).

Comment: The docs seem to be incorrect, if I am reading the source code correctly.

Comment: Seems you are right - source code is source of truth. I'll check it.