# Start service without activity

Tags: android

Is it possible to start a service without starting an activity? My plan is to write an application which shows a notification when Bluetooth device is connected and a headset
Thanks for answers

Comment: What have you tried? What issues did you encounter?

Comment: Nothing I don't know how to do it

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909683/launch-android-application-without-main-activity-and-start-service-on-launching

Answer (score -1):

Services **ONLY** can be started from Android components , such as `Activity` , `BroadcastReceiver` and either from another `service`. Anyway to start a service you need a `Context` , Because you're gonna call `Context.startService(i)`.

In your case I suggest you to start your service from a `BroadcastReceiver` as same as this one :
[How to detect when a user plugs headset on android device? (Opposite of ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13610258/how-to-detect-when-a-user-plugs-headset-on-android-device-opposite-of-action-a)

Comment: And how can i do it with a bluetooth headset?