# Turn on HeadPhone mode by code in android

Tags: android

My phone not detect headphone when I plug my headphone. So I want turn on headphone mode manually to listen by headphone instead by speaker. Can I do it by code? Thank you so much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect when a user plugs headset on android device? (Opposite of ACTION\_AUDIO\_BECOMING\_NOISY)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13610258/how-to-detect-when-a-user-plugs-headset-on-android-device-opposite-of-action-a)

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help

```
AudioManager mAudioMgr = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
mAudioMgr.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
         mAudioMgr.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
         mAudioMgr.setWiredHeadsetOn(true);
```

Comment: Thank you!, but setWiredHeadsetOn deprecated