# Alarm when disconnect the headphone jack

Tags: android, android-audiomanager, soundpool

I'm literry new in Andriod and I want to create a app to Alarm the user when disconnect the headphones when the jack is unplugged the phone launch an alarm in the speakers, well, my code detect when the jack is unplugged even when the phone launches the alarm but this alarm do not sound in the speakers but when I connect the heaphones the alarm can be listened in the headphones, you can help me whit this? I dont know whats happen

Comment: Can you share some part of your code? Atleast how you are playing the alarm and setting it up.

Comment: thanks so much, I resolved the problem using this code:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13610258/how-to-detect-when-a-user-plugs-headset-on-android-device-opposite-of-action-a